# How can i fix this mesh glitch?

Tags: mesh

I only added the smooth modifier and all this weird shading appeared, how do I get rid of it?

[image][image]

Comment: Check face Normal orientation

Comment: You don't have enough geometry for this.  Either use Laplacian, lower smoothing values or a subsurf modifier to smooth this out.